# ServiceStack OpenId AuthProviders on Mono

Tags: mono, servicestack, ubuntu-12.04, dotnetopenauth

The problem is that OpenId Auth providers aren't working under Ubuntu 12.04 with nginx/1.1.19, Mono JIT compiler version 3.1.1, fastcgi-mono-server4.exe 2.10.0.0

The ServiceStack references were all pulled via Nuget are at version 3.9.55.0, including ServiceStack.Authentication.OpenId which is attached to DotNetOpenAuth 4.3.0.0

The project is based on the ServiceStack Template CustomPath40 and all of the projects are built under .NET 4 with VS2012 on Win7x64.

Every auth works perfectly fine under IIS8/IIS8 Express. I configured the authproviders in AppHost, emulating the SocialBootstrapApi. Twitter and Facebook auth works just fine on mono, once running:

```
 mozroots --import --ask-remove
```

that trusts typical mozilla certs.

The OpenId providers will complain about lacking a log4net dll (again, only on mono), but supplying an appropriate log4net dll quiets that error. Now the OpenId providers (Google and Yahoo) both throw an exception:

```
 Method not found: 'System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Dispose'.

[Auth: 07/26/2013 04:21:13]:
[REQUEST: {provider:GoogleOpenId}] System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Dispose'. at
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.HmacShaAssociation/HmacSha.CreateHasher (byte[]) <0x00017> at
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.HmacShaAssociation.CreateHasher () <0x0001b> at
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Association.Sign (byte[]) <0x00034> at
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.SigningBindingElement.GetSignature (DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ITamperResistantOpenIdMessage,DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Association) <0x001f3> at
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.SigningBindingElement.ProcessIncomingMessage (DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.IProtocolMessage) <0x00133> at
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.ProcessIncomingMessage (DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.IProtocolMessage) <0x001b1> at
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.OpenIdChannel.ProcessIncomingMessage (DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.IProtocolMessage) <0x000f3> at
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.ReadFromRequest (System.Web.HttpRequestBase) <0x00359> at
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.GetResponse (System.Web.HttpRequestBase) <0x00053> at
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.GetResponse () <0x0006f> at
ServiceStack.Authentication.OpenId.OpenIdOAuthProvider.Authenticate (ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.IServiceBase,ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.IAuthSession,ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth) <0x00693> at
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.AuthService.Authenticate (ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth,string,ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.IAuthSession,ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.IAuthProvider) <0x0004f> at
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.AuthService.Post (ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth) <0x00247> at
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.AuthService.Get (ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth) <0x00013> at
(wrapper dynamic-method) object.lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,object,object) <0x0004f> at
ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceRunner`1<ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth>.Execute (ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IRequestContext,object,ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth) <0x001de>
```

The obvious problem would be the one detailed here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3375, but this is marked as resolved over a year ago in 2.10.x, while I built this 3.1.1 from tagged source last week.

How can I remedy this exception and get the OpenId Auth providers working on Mono?

Comment: seems like a broken Mono install, how did you install Mono 3.x?

Comment: @knocte Here's the script I wrote to do so: http://pastebin.com/7KjLeinc pulled from a few blog posts

Comment: you're not installing xsp into /usr/local in your script, so then you're mixing xsp with 2 versions of mono, which are becoming conflicted, please read http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments

Comment: @knocte Thanks for the quick replies. So those exported bash vars would alter the build to a different location? I would like to remove any existing mono rather than run two simultaneously. Also, perhaps my understanding is flawed (new to this environment), but I was trying to use mono-fastcgi-server4 as the junction between nginx and mono. Isn't that an alternative to XSP?  I included more of the full script into http://pastebin.com/jmdM2r1q and I use apt-get to pull in mono-fastcgi-server4. Should I build that from a source somewhere?

Comment: when I said xsp I didn't mean the xsp server but the xsp repo (which includes mono-fastcgi): https://github.com/mono/xsp

Comment: so you need to install that xsp repo (3.0.11 tag) into /usr/local, and use the new mono-fastcgi from it

Comment: @knocte Ah, I see. I ran through the build process and everything's working great. Thanks very much, you've been a big help.  For future peoples' reference, here's the relevant portion of the script: http://pastebin.com/TBVQwp5L

Comment: glad to hear that, I'll create a reply now so we can make everything clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You claim to have installed Mono 3.1.1, but you didn't install xsp with the scripts that you used to install this new version of Mono.

This means then, that when you installed xsp from packages, you pulled in Mono 2.x as a dependency of it. So you thought you had uninstalled mono from packages, and installed a new Mono, but you were actually having 2 versions of Mono at the same time.

When running xsp from packages, you where running the binary located at /usr, which means it was using the old mono (not the new one that you installed in /usr/local).

Even if you're running `mono-fastcgi-server4` instead of the xsp server, both servers codebase is common: the xsp repo, which you need to install alongside Mono: http://github.com/xsp