# Running Mono 3.2.0 with .NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, apache, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, asp.net-4.5

I am trying to get Mono 3.0 setup to run MVC4 sites under .NET 4 and .NET 4.5.  I've been working through various errors, what can I do to get it up and running?

**Server Configuration**

- CentOS 5
- Apache 2.2.3
- 3.2.0 (tarball Sun Jul 28 00:57:40 UTC 2013); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020
  2013)
- Latest XSP from git, as of the time of this post

**Apache/Mono Config**

```
MonoServerPath "/usr/local/bin/mod-mono-server4"
```

/usr/local/bin/mod-mono-server4 contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/local/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS "/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mod-mono-server4.exe" "$@"
```

**Update**

The crux of the problem is that Mono doesn't ship with MVC4 which the site requires.  It still has the MVC3 dlls, yet it has the Razor 2 dlls but not the Razor 1 dlls which MVC3 wants to sue.

Comment: Maybe this can be on some help: http://blog.miraclespain.com/archive/2013/Jun-24.html you can get most of the references that is missing from nuget instead of building all of it from scratch with mono

Comment: Thanks for the link.  MVC3 apps actually work fine - MVC3 is now rolled up into the mono codebase.

Comment: I don't think the NullReferenceException you're getting has anything to do with MVC4 in Mono, I think you have a broken mono installation (smells like it because you're using the /usr/local prefix), so I'm downvoting your question and answer

Comment: see this for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874626/servicestack-openid-authproviders-on-mono/17909771#17909771

Comment: @knocte I was able to reproduce the problem on a fresh install of Cent OS 6.6 with a fresh install of the latest sources of XSP and MOD_MONO from Git and the 3.2.0 tarball from 7/24. /usr/local seems to be the default install location on Cent OS. Are you currently able to run .NET MVC4 under Mono?

Comment: @knocte I was a little hasty in updating the top portion of my post. There were actually two separate problems, the first is solved and the second seems to be related to my conclusion below.  For one, System.Web.Mvc makes use of UnvalidatedRequestValuesBase which I can't find anywhere in the Mono source.  Maybe I am missing something, but I couldn't find it in the source, or get MVC4 to build against what's currently in Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Success**

If you want to run MVC4 on Mono, you need to use some Microsoft dlls which are not provided by Mono at this time.

*A word of caution -* Taking a cursory look at the Mono source, there appears to be methods and classes in the MC4 source that do not exist in the 3.2.0 build.  There may be features that are broken. The site I am running is for all intents and purposes an MVC3 site built against the latest dlls.

**Microsoft DLLs to copy**

- System.Web.Abstractions - 4.0
- System.Web.Helpers - 2.0
- System.Web.Mvc - 4.0

Once you copy over the dlls, if you're still having problems you may have to do some detective work if the above fix doesn't work.  If you get an error message saying that Mono can't find the DLL, it's usually one of three reasons:

**Troubleshooting**

1. Is doesn't have the dll - *You can try using the Microsoft version of the DLL*
2. It's looking for an older version of the DLL when the correct one is installed in the GAC or in your project folder - *An assembly in your project is likely referencing that version somewhere. You can use a binding re-direct to force the specific version you have be used instead*
3. It stil can't find the dll - *Add the assembly in the compilation/assemblies section of your web.config*
4. You're getting a 'can't find view searched...' message - *if any of the views in that particular views folder have compile errors, then you'll receive this message.*

Comment: also note for the 'can't find view searched...' message I found on my ubuntu 16.04 server this was caused by Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.dll being in the bin directory dunno why it causes this error but upon deleting that dll and setting VS 2010 copy local to false the website immediately started working like a champ even with simple membership and MySQL instead of ms sql

Answer (score 5):

Everything you need is now available within the Mono framework or on NuGet. I've created downloadable template for MVC4 for .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5 and some notes on resolving the issues:

http://www.cafe-encounter.net/p1510/asp-net-mvc4-net-framework-version-4-5-c-razor-template-for-mono-on-mac-and-linux

The steps from the blog post are:

- git clone
  github.com/chrisfcarroll/AspNetTemplatesForMono/Mvc4CSharpRazorFx45Intranet
  NB This github repo includes all the required dlls in case you don’t
  have NuGet working, so it’s an oversized download.
- Open the solution in Xamarin Studio. It almost works out-of-the-box.
  The one thing you have to do is choose one of these 2 steps to make
  it work:

Either delete Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll from the bin\ directory and from the project

Or, from the command line:

```
sudo mkdir /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.5/etc/mono/registry
sudo chmod g+rwx /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.5/etc/mono/registry
```

(replacing 3.2.5 with your mono version, which you get at the command line with mono --version);

The Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll is required on .Net on Windows, so deleting it is not the simpler approach if you want cross-platform deployability