# Hosting MVC application on linux server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debian, hosting

I am developing an MVC 4 application on windows and that is to be hosted on Debian. I am a newbie to web development. I am using Mariadb in backend.

I don't know how to deploy this application. Can anybody provide help to me?

**UPDATE**

I am using `Mono 3.2.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to host a Microsoft asp.net mvc 4 Application on Linux UNLESS you use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) (Never tried it but the honey is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900677/running-mono-3-2-0-with-net-mvc-4) ).

OR

If you don't want to buy mono,
Wait for `vNext` ! He Will be among us around April 2015 as Microsoft Announced at the DotNet-Conf.

MEANWHILE

you can download `VisualStudio 2014 CTP` and taste the golden `kvm`

[More resources](http://www.asp.net/vnext)

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. Yes I am using Mono. I have updated my question. I am having some issues in development but that is off the topic. What is the simplest way to deploy this MVC application on mono is what I want to know. :)

Comment: Are you facing this issue with asp.net web application or with mvc only?

Comment: With both, ASP.NET and MVC

Comment: Please follow the link in my anwer " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900677/running-mono-3-2-0-with-net-mvc-4 "

Answer (score 0):

I'm running 4 MVC4 sites on my Ubuntu 16.04 server and all I did was install a ftp server and I put all the sites in my user home dir under public_html (eg: public_html/site1 public_html/site2) then use the ftp publish method of visual studio which will build the site and copy everything over via ftp then you can just browse your site.