# How to host .NET MVC 4 Web Application on AIX Operating System

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, hosting, aix

I got a requirement from my client to host a web application (developed under .net framework 4.5 and mvc 4) on his AIX operating system.

Can anybody have an idea, whether is it possible and if yes how it can be done ?

I am too searching for it, but as the resources for this question are bit less on internet, hence I request a help from techies on stack platform.

Thanks in advance.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2018 Mono is now supported on AIX so it might be possible: [Introducing Mono on AIX and IBM i](https://www.mono-project.com/news/2018/05/29/mono-on-aix-and-ibm-i/)

Answer (score 0):

Right now, running .NET applications on other platforms than Windows is made possible by the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/). But only MacOS X, Linux (many distributions) and Windows are supported: Xamarin (that now develops and supports Mono) provides packages for those operating systems. [In 2010, the CTO of Xamarin answered that AIX was not supported](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5175/how-to-install-mono-in-aix#answer-5243). He said it is possible to port Mono to AIX, but would not be easy.

Comment: Also note that [hosting ASP.NET MVC 4 apps with Mono may require some steps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900677/running-mono-3-2-0-with-net-mvc-4#answer-21103371).